# Matplotlib datetime x-axis formatting can't handle many time values

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-datetime

I'm trying to format the x-axis ticks for some hourly data from 2021. The x-axis are date times of the type `datetime64[ns]`. I'd like to have ticks only on the first of each month (Jan, Feb, ..., Dec). If there are too many data points, the x-axis date time tick labels show the wrong year and there are far too many, like the first image below. If I then remove a significant fraction of the data, I'm able to get sensible tick labels, like in the second image. How can I format these plots with all of the data to get xticks and labels for only the first of the month?

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

times=pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2021-12-31', freq='1h')
adf = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': times,
    'A': np.random.rand(times.shape[0]),
    'B': np.random.rand(times.shape[0]) * 100
})

# uncomment to remove a lot of the data and I can properly format the ticks
# for col in adf.columns:
#     adf.loc[adf.sample(frac=0.7).index, col] = np.nan

adf.set_index('time', inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)

ax2 = ax.twinx()

a = adf.plot(y='A', ax=ax, color='blue', alpha=0.3, legend=False)
b = adf.plot(y='B', ax=ax2, color='red', alpha=0.3, legend=False)

ax.legend([
    a.get_lines()[0],
    b.get_lines()[0]
], ['A', 'B'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%y'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30)
```

#### All of the data with far too many ticks and tick labels for some reason

The output of `ax.get_xticklabels()`:

```
[Text(447088.0, 0, '02-01-94'),
 Text(447116.0, 0, '03-01-94'),
 Text(447147.0, 0, '04-01-94'),
 Text(447177.0, 0, '05-01-94'),
 Text(447208.0, 0, '06-01-94'),
 Text(447238.0, 0, '07-01-94'),
 Text(447269.0, 0, '08-01-94'),
 Text(447300.0, 0, '09-01-94'),
 Text(447330.0, 0, '10-01-94'),
 Text(447361.0, 0, '11-01-94'), ...]
```

[image: Ticks when all of the data is present are wrong]

#### Dropping much of the data leaves me with the proper number of ticks

[image: Dropping a lot of the data properly formats the ticks, but then I lose data]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that occurs because of [pandas installing its own locator and tick formatters](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23343).

Removing the use of pandas time objects works:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

times=pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2021-12-31', freq='1h').to_pydatetime()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)

ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax.plot(times, np.random.rand(times.shape[0]), color='blue', alpha=0.3)
ax2.plot(times, np.random.rand(times.shape[0]) * 100, color='red', alpha=0.3)
              
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d-%y'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30)
```